# Why does my function keep returning an empty list?

Tags: racket

I am writing an `upper-threshold` function in Racket that takes two arguments: a list of numbers and an integer.

All it has to do is recursively go through the list and return a list of integers that are below the value of the given integer. However, my function always spits out an empty list. I feel like it has something to do with how I am using the append function.

I have displayed the values that should be appended to my empty list z, and they are correct, but for some reason they are not appending to the list!

```
(define (upper-threshold x y [z '()])
  (cond [(null? x) z]
    [else (cond [(< (first x) y) (append (list (first x)) z) (upper-threshold (rest x) y)]
          [else (upper-threshold (rest x) y)])]))
```

For example, a call and return should look like this:

`(upper-threshold '(1 2 3 5 6) 4)
'(1 2 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't including the third argument, `z`, in any of the recursive calls to `upper-threshold`. This means that on each iteration, `z` will always be the empty list. Furthermore, Racket's `append` doesn't mutate the lists it operates on. This means the expression `(append (list (first x)) z)` produces an entirely new list instead of changing `x` or `z`.

```lisp
(cond [(< (first x) y)
       (append (list (first x)) z) ; produces a new list which is not used, x and z
                                   ; remain unchanged
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y ; no z argument passed in here, defaults to '()
       )]
      [else
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y ; no z argument passed in here, defaults to '()
       )])
```

All we need to do is provide the correct third argument to each recursive call.

```lisp
(cond [(< (first x) y)
       (define new-z (append (list (first x)) z))
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y new-z)]
      [else
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y z)])
```

Also: whenever you want to add an element onto the front of a list, it's easier to use the function `cons` instead of `append`. Thus, `(append (list (first x)) z)` becomes `(cons (first x) z)`.

```lisp
(cond [(< (first x) y)
       (define new-z (cons (first x) z))
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y new-z)]
      [else
       (upper-threshold (rest x) y z)])
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I was definitely confused about how the append function works along with recursive calling of the arguments. Thank you so much.